# Strip H1 tag and its contents

Tags: php

How can i remove

```
<h1>and its contents</h1>
```

from the following line

```
strip_tags(substr($article->content(),0,255)
```

from this complete code

```
<?php $last_articles = $this->children(array('limit'=>5, 'order'=>'page.created_on DESC')); ?>
<?php foreach ($last_articles as $article): ?>
<div class="entry">
  <h3><?php echo $article->link($article->title); ?></h3>
  <?php echo strip_tags(substr($article->content(),0,255).'...', '<p><a>'); ?>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$my_title = preg_replace('/<h1[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/h1[^>]*>/', '', $article->content());
```

Related Resource:

http://sarfraznawaz.wordpress.com/2009/09/08/dreamweaver-tip-search-replace-code-snippets/